# check and compare an array within an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble checking the contents of an array contained within a main array.

Example:

I have two arrays

```
var main = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]];
var compare = [1,2,4,5,6]
```

I want to compare the array "compare" with each array within the array "main" to see if it contains any of the numbers. The result would be something I could then test against (boolean or the index position).

I tried indexOf and couldn't figure it out.

**Edit**
This should still return true:

```
var main = [[1,2,3], // returns false
           [4,5,6], // returns false
           [7,8,9], // returns true
           [2,3,7]]; // returns true

var compare = [2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
```

** Update w/ Solution ***

I needed to check if compare array's contents matched any of the subarrays in main. Here's what I came up with:

```
var main = [[1, 2, 3],
      [4,5,6]];

var counter = 0;
var counter2 = 0;

var compare = [4,1,3,2];

for (var i = 0; i <= compare.length; i++) {
// Sorting 
compare.sort();

if (main[0].indexOf(compare[i]) > -1) {
    counter++;
    console.log("Added a point to counter 1");
} else if (main[1].indexOf(compare[i]) > -1) {      
    counter2++;
    console.log("Added a point to counter 2");
} else {   
  console.log("No points added");
}
}

// if any of the counters have 3 marks, then the player hit it 3 times.
if (counter == 3 || counter2 === 3){
console.log("A counter is at 3");
}
```

Any feedback on what I came up with? What's a better way of doing this?

Comment: For loops + indexOf should help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 2 loops, the first to iterate over your array of arrays, the next to check for existing elements within the current array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < main.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < main[i].length; j++) {
        if (compare.indexOf(main[i][j]) {
            //compare has a number from the current array! main[i][j] exists in compare!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's returning a error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at lodash library, the have that exact functionality written already

Comment: Why use a library if three lines of very simple code can do the job?

Comment: That is true, you don't need a library to do this. How ever good libraries have good unit test coverage and take into account browser differences. I'm all for pure javascript an all, but there is no reason to reinvent the wheel ether...

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in array methods:

```
var result = main.map(function(xs) {
  return xs.some(function(x) {
    return compare.indexOf(x) > -1
  })
})
```

It will return `[true, true]`

Answer (score 0):

Following, two of the possible solutions:

Suppose:

```
var main = [[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9],
            [2,3,7],
            [5,1,10]];

var compare = [2,3,4,6,7,8,9];
```

---

**First solution**: return true if any element of the `main` inner array is included in the master one which is `compare`:

```
var result1= main.map(function(element,index,array){
    return element.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
        return (previousValue || (compare.indexOf(currentValue) >= 0));
    }, false);
});
```

This solution gives the following result:

```
result1 = [true,true,true,true,false]
```

---

**Second solution**: return the index of the `main` inner array elements in `compare`:

```
var result2= main.map(function(element,index,array){
    return element.map(function(element,index,array){
        return (compare.indexOf(element));
    });
});
```

This solution gives the following result:

```
result2 = [[-1,0,1],[2,-1,3],[4,5,6],[0,1,4],[-1,-1,-1]]
```

---

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/a6nLfwm0/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!